# MetricsGraphics.js linking two charts with different "chart_type" properties (javascript)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, metricsgraphicsjs

I'm using [MetricsGraphics.js](https://www.metricsgraphicsjs.org) to plot a simple time series.  I'm having trouble linking a "line" chart with a "point" chart using the `linked: true` option.  The linking works when both charts are of the same type, but not when they're different.

The following jsfiddles show this.  In the first, when you hover over data points in one chart, the points in both charts are highlighted.  In the second, hovering over data points in one chart doesn't affect the other.

Both charts have `chart_type: 'line'`: [jsfiddle.net/7jc1h8vv](https://jsfiddle.net/7jc1h8vv/)

One chart has `chart_type: 'point'`, the other `chart_type: 'line'`: [jsfiddle.net/7jc1h8vv/1](https://jsfiddle.net/7jc1h8vv/1/)

**Question:** How can I link a "point" chart and a "line" chart together?  Alternatively, if that can't be done, then how can I create data symbols for each data point on the line in a 'line' chart, such that the two charts are effectively superimposed?

---

The MetricsGraphics.js library provides an option `linked: true` that will do the following, [according to the doc](https://github.com/mozilla/metrics-graphics/wiki/Graphic#linked):

> Links together all other graphs whose *linked* option is set to true. When one graphic in that set is rolled over, the corresponding values in the other graphics are also rolled over.

See [this example](https://www.metricsgraphicsjs.org/examples.htm#linked_multi1) from the doc of two charts linked together.